# Unplugged wireless access point

Tags: wifi, hub

Would a powered down wireless access point, that is hooked up to hub/switch, cause any network problems?

Comment: This is the oddest IT version of "if a tree falls in a forest" I've ever seen.

Answer (score 6):

Other than occupying a switch port you could be using for something else? Not likely.

Comment: Unless it's PoE and powers itself back up as a result of the switch being power-cycled.

Comment: Now that's out of the box thinking :)

Comment: Might be an indication that I've seen/experienced that very thing.

Comment: So was it a device with a physical power switch? Or was it one of those switches which is dependent on the last power state, like a PC?

Answer (score 2):

No, but a powered-up access point improperly configured or connected to an improperly configured switch port can eat packets, and some switches can deliver power to access points via PoE... so it could be possible that the access point in question is still involved.